# Suppose $Z \sim Bern(p(X))$ and $Y = \beta X$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$. Does this imply $E(ZY) = E(Y)P(Z=1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $Z \sim Bern(p(X))$, where $p(X)$ is a logistic function of $X$. Then let $Y = \beta X$ where $\beta$ is a constant. Then, let $X \sim N(0,1)$. Does this imply $E(ZY) = E(Y)P(Z=1) = \beta E(X) p(X)$?

In other words, in general is it true that for $Z \sim Bern(p(X))$

$$
E\left[ZY\right] = E\left[1\cdot Y\right]P(Z=1) + E\left[0\cdot Y\right]P(Z=0)
$$
?

I am a bit unsure here as we have $Y$ and $Z$ both a function of the same variable $X$. Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}\left(ZY\mid X=x\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(Z\beta X\mid X=x\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(Z\beta x\mid X=x\right)=\beta x\mathbb{E}\left(Z\mid X=x\right)=\beta xP\left(x\right)$$

So: $$\mathbb{E}\left(ZY\mid X\right)=\beta XP\left(X\right)$$ and consequently:
$$\mathbb{E}ZY=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(ZY\mid X\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\beta XP\left(X\right)\right]=\beta\mathbb{E}\left[XP\left(X\right)\right]$$